# execStats is always empty in MongoDB "aggregate" commands profiling results

Tags: mongodb, performance, profiling, aggregation-framework

I am trying to profile the performance of an aggregation pipeline, specifically checking whether indices are used, how many objects are scanned, etc.

I'm setting the DB to full profiling:

> db.setProfilingLevel(2)

But then in the db's 'system.profile' collection, in the result record for the aggregation command, the execStats is always empty.

Here is the full result for the command:

```
{
  "op" : "command",
  "ns" : "mydb.$cmd",
  "command" : {
    "aggregate" : "mycolection",
    "pipeline" : [{
        "$match" : {
          "date" : {
            "$gte" : "2013-11-26"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "$sort" : {
          "user_id" : 1
        }
      }, {
        "$project" : {
          "user_id" : 1,
          "_id" : 0
        }
      }, {
        "$group" : {
          "_id" : "$user_id",
          "agg_val" : {
            "$sum" : 1
          }
        }
      }],
    "allowDiskUse" : true
  },
  "keyUpdates" : 0,
  "numYield" : 16,
  "lockStats" : {
    "timeLockedMicros" : {
      "r" : NumberLong(3143653),
      "w" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
      "r" : NumberLong(140),
      "w" : NumberLong(3)
    }
  },
  "responseLength" : 4990,
  "millis" : 3237,
  "execStats" : { },
  "ts" : ISODate("2014-11-26T16:20:59.576Z"),
  "client" : "127.0.0.1",
  "allUsers" : [],
  "user" : ""
}
```

Comment: Use `db.collection.aggregate(..., { "explain" : true })` to get information about indexes used, nscanned, etc.

Comment: I tried using {"explain" : true} with aggregate, but it appears that it just calculates the plan, and doesn't actually execute the query, and thus I'm not getting the nscanned stats, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Support `execStats` for `aggregation` command was added in [mongo 3.4](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23264).